# How do I clear all checks in UITableVIew when VC is returned to from another VC?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a scenario where a UITableView shows a list of players in a league.

The user selects two players to compare results.  As a user selects a player a check is shown.  Once the user has selected two users a new VC is presented, showing the results of the two players.

On this ResultsVC I have a back button which dismisses ResultsVC, and the view is returned to the originalVC.

Upon returning to this originalVC the checks next to the players which were selected for viewing are still visible.

How do I reset all checks when this VC is returned to?

This is my code for the original VC with the TableView:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonalStatsTableViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PersonalStatsTableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.communityPlayers[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 12)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white // set to any colour
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    cell.personalStatsInfoButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.personalStatsInfoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(infoClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return cell

}

func infoClicked(sender:UIButton){
    let buttonRow = sender.tag
    self.friendId = self.communityPlayerIds[buttonRow]
    self.personalSelf = false
    self.friendName = self.communityPlayers[buttonRow]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "personalStatsSegue", sender: self)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.selectedCellTitle = self.communityPlayers[indexPath.row]
    cellId = indexPath.row
    //print (self.communityPlayerIds[indexPath.row])

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        if cell.isSelected {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }

    if let sr = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        print("didSelectRowAtIndexPath selected rows:\(sr)")
        if sr.count == 2{
            let tempId_1 = sr[0][1]
            let tempId_2 = sr[1][1]
            self.tempCount = 2
            self.tempPlayerId_1 = self.communityPlayerIds[tempId_1]
            self.tempPlayerId_2 = self.communityPlayerIds[tempId_2]

            print ("you have selected player I'ds: ", self.tempPlayerId_1!, "and ", self.tempPlayerId_2!)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showHeadToHeadSegue", sender: self)
        }


    }


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    if let sr = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        print("didDeselectRowAtIndexPath selected rows:\(sr)")

    }


}
}
```

I have read around the subject but nothing appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

sussed it.

I added

```
cell.accessoryType = .none
```

into the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` function

Then when the view is returned all checks are removed.